# Issues with github ignoring profile name

Tags: github

For some reason GitHub always uses my personal name when I raise issues etc, I have a profile name set which is different but it never uses that.

To clarify - personal name is Joe Bloggs

I login as joebloggs

My profile name is joethedev

How do I get commits etc to be flagged as by joethedev not joebloggs??

Comment: What exactly do you mean by profile name? Your username is what you login with.

Answer (score 0):

How can you login as **joebloggs** when your profile name is **joethedev**. I usually login with my email and my profile name (username) is set via the **Settings -> Account**

Comment: I don't know that's just how GitHub works for me, if I try to log in as joethedev it won't work.  joethedev is set as my profile name but it won't let me chamge my username to that, strange.

Comment: Sorry then, I cannot help

Comment: @AlanDev It doesn't let you change probably because someone else has taken that username already. Perhaps joethedev is your profile name on some other service connected to github, and not github itself? What does your profile URL say?